How do I tell MacOS to open TextEdit app at certain X and Y coordinates using a plist variable?
I've been looking at plist variables while trying to set the position and size of a window when the editor is launched. But I'm failing to guess or find the name of plist key for this.
I was following similar advice here but without success so far.
defaults read $HOME/Library/Containers/com.apple.TextEdit/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist HeightInChars

I'm not working with multiple monitors which I hope makes it easier.
